# group rows if atleast one word overlaps with other in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as below

```
       words    group_id
0  set([a, c, b, d])   1
1        set([a, b])   2
2  set([h, e, g, f])   3
```

I need to group the rows into one even if one word in the set(words) overlaps with a word in set of other row and update the group_id.

```
       words    group_id
0  set([a, c, b, d])   1
1        set([a, b])   1
2  set([h, e, g, f])   3
```

I tried this way

```
word_frequency = Counter()

for val in df['words'].values:
    word_frequency.update(val)

to_return = np.array(word_frequency.most_common())
count = 1

df['group_id'] = np.zeros(len(df)) * np.nan
for val in to_return:
    df['group_id'] = df[['group_id','words']].apply(lambda x: count if (val in x) else np.NAN)
    count += 1
```

How can I do that?

Comment: plz post what you've tried

Comment: How many rows are there?

Comment: in the example above it is 3. in real time the dataframe size varies each time.

Comment: ```set([c, x])``` overlaps row zero but not row one - rows zero and one overlap.  Is ```set([c, x])``` grouped with both rows zero and one?

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to store the data as a python set in the `words` column? How many unique words are there?  I have a feeling that in the current setup, it can be very inefficient, whereas if we expand into, for example, a crosstabulated matrix then it would be much more efficient. If the latter is possible, then it'll be more straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty inefficient and hacked-together solution, but works nonetheless:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Names":[set(["a", "c", "b", "d"]),set(["a", "b"]),set(["h", "e", "g", "f"]),set(["z"])]})

groups={}
idx=0
data=[]
for row in df.itertuples():
    values = row.Names
    groups[idx] = values
    for i in range(len(groups)):
        if len(values.intersection(groups[i])) > 0:
            not_found = False
            data.append(i)
            if len(groups[i]) - len(groups[idx]) > 0:
                groups[i] = values      #Replace with the larger set
            if idx>0:
                groups.pop(idx, None)
                idx-=1
        else:
            not_found = True
            break
        break
    if not_found:
        data.append(idx)
    idx+=1

df['group id'] = data
```

result:

```
          Names  group id
0  {c, d, a, b}         0
1        {a, b}         0
2  {e, h, f, g}         1
3           {z}         2
```

You should still favor a solution that uses the apply method rather than iterating through every row in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

This works but it's pretty inefficient since its producing a set of unique groupings then searching through this set of unique groupings once for each entry in the dataframe. Would be neat to see more efficient ways of doing this.

```
def unique_grouper(series_of_entry_sets):
    set_of_groups = [series_of_entry_sets[0]]
    for potential_set in series_of_entry_sets:
        for i,accepted_set in enumerate(set_of_groups, start = 1):
            if accepted_set & potential_set:
                break
            else:
                set_of_groups.append(potential_set)
                break
    return set_of_groups

def group_identifier(current_set,set_of_groups):
    for i,unique_group in enumerate(set_of_groups):
        if current_set & unique_group:
            return i
    return None

df = pd.DataFrame({"Names":[set(["a", "c", "b", "d"]),set(["a", "b"]),set(["h", "e", "g", "f"]),set(["z"])]})
result =unique_grouper(df.Names)
df["group id"] = df.Names.apply(lambda x:group_identifier(x,result))
```

Output:

```
          Names  group id
0  {a, c, b, d}         0
1        {a, b}         0
2  {h, e, g, f}         1
3           {z}         2
```